# Do all YEC believe flat earth?

Tags: young-earth-creation, earth

What I mean "all YEC" is : since from the past until now there is not one person of YEC believe that the earth is a ball shape.

For example, God said in :

> Daniel 4:11 (ESV) 
>  The tree grew and became strong, and its top
>   reached to heaven, and **it was visible to the end of the whole earth**
>
> Matthew 4:8 (ESV)
>  Again, the devil took him to a very high
>   mountain and **showed him all the kingdoms of the world** and their glory.

Since if the earth is a ball shape then it's impossible that the bold event to occur, so is there any YEC who don't believe that the bold event in those two verses really happen ?

Also in the creation event :

> Genesis 1:6 (ESV)
>  And God said, “Let there be an expanse in the
>   midst of the waters, and let it separate the waters from the waters.”

Comment: What does young-earth creationism have to do with a flat earth?  People who believe in young-earth creationism do not believe that every phrase in the Bible must be understood in a woodenly literal way.

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/2034/23657. Related

Comment: @Nathaniel, Wiki said : _"Young Earth creationists have claimed that their view has its earliest roots in ancient Judaism"_ So, though it has not been said as YEC, there were already Jewish people who believe that the earth is young in ancient times. So, there were "YEC" long time ago. How they believe that, I think it must be from a literal reading of the creation account in OT. I wonder, did this ancient "YEC" believe that the earth is spherical that time ?

Comment: @Kris, there is no "acceptable" answer in the link you gave me :). The Hebrew word "chug" can mean a circle like a coin besides a ball. If ancient Jews read other verses (for example in Daniel 4:11) - it seems more likely they will choose "chug" as a coin then a ball.

Comment: @karma, Context, always context. In Daniel 4:11 Nebuchadnezzar is relating "a vision" he saw "while lying in bed." (v.10).  In a vision anything can happen; e.g. Jesus can appear as a 7-horned 7-eyed lamb (Rev. 5:6), something that was plainly not a literal reality.  Likewise Matt. 4:8, even if the earth were flat it would not be possible to physically see "all the kingdoms of the world" -- they'd be too far, thousands of miles, for the human eye to make out. So it must have also been a vision, not a literal seeing.

Comment: @JDM-GBG, you wrote : _"In a vision anything can happen"_. So, what about the creation account ?

Comment: @karma, what about it?  You're implying that the creation account declares the Earth to be flat.  If so, then provide a quote to substantiate the implication.

Comment: @JDM-GBG, that's not what I mean in my question :). What I mean in my question : _is the creation account (we read in Gen 1) a vision saw by the author of Gen 1 ?_

Comment: @karma, what does this have to do with the OP?

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the OP, JDM. I ask the question from what you say : _In a vision anything can happen_, which I thought that what you mean is : _In a vision anything illogical can happen_ something like (a) 7-horned 7-eyed lamb (b) a tree which visible to the end of the whole earth. (continue)

Comment: So, regarding the Creation account - if it's a vision then the event might not happen in reality.  But in the pov YEC, it happen in reality although it's a vision. So, applying on how the OT people's mind - why then it's impossible if they think that in reality a tree which so tall can be seen to the end of the whole earth although it's a vision ?

Comment: @karma, yes, in a vision anything non-literal -- including illogical -- can happen.  We know that Nebuchanezzar's tall tree was a vision because he said so himself in Daniel 4:10 -- *Thus were **the visions of mine head in my bed**; I saw, and behold a tree in the midst of the earth, and the height thereof was great.*  But there is no such statement in the Genesis 1 creation account, it is simply a narrative description:  God did this, then this, then that, and so on.  It doesn't say "I was lying in bed and saw a vision of God creating."

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be No.

As an example, John MacArthur of "Grace To You" ministries is a YEC:

https://www.gty.org/library/blog/B100702/indications-of-a-young-earth

> But what if you start with a different set of assumptions? What if you
>   go to the evidence assuming the biblical record is true, namely, that
>   the earth is relatively young and there was a cataclysmic event known
>   as the Flood?
>
> That’s what John MacArthur assumes, and as he listens to scientists
>   with similar assumptions, he finds that there are many indications of
>   a young earth.

But he acknowledges the fact that the Earth is not flat:

https://www.gty.org/library/sermons-library/90-326/biblical-inspiration-validated-by-science-part-1

> Whoever made this earth understands that is spherical and not flat. 
>   He understands that it rotates on an axis,  not that it is stationary
>   with heaven rotating around it.  Whoever it was that created this
>   earth knows that it is suspended in space on nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer JDM. The quote : _"Whoever made this earth understands that is spherical and not flat_". So, what verse in OT which can be concluded that the earth is spherical not flat - which later on validated by science ? Is there a flat-earth believer who believe that the earth is young ?

Comment: @karma, check the answers from this question:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/does-the-bible-suggest-that-the-earth-is-round?rq=1

Comment: JDM, I just found out in the internet about Augustine's view : _""But as to the fable that there are Antipodes, that is to say, men on the opposite side of the earth, where the sun rises when it sets to us, men who walk with their feet opposite ours, that is on no ground credible."_  (http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/120116.htm)

Comment: @karma, Augustine wasn't questioning the shape of the earth, only the idea that "the far side" was inhabited.  Later in the writing you quote from, he goes on:  "...although it be supposed or scientifically demonstrated that the world is of a round and spherical form, yet it does not follow that the other side of the earth is bare of water; nor even, though it be bare, does it immediately follow that it is peopled."

Comment: JDM, I think _"**it does not follow** that the other side of the earth is bare of water; nor even, though it be bare, does it immediately follow that it is peopled"_ is Augustine's argument. So, because _"it does not follow bla3x"_ then "_there are Antipodes_" is a fable.

Comment: @karma, that's what I said.  Augustine was rejecting the idea that the opposite side of the world was inhabited.  He was not rejecting the idea that the world is round.  He was still wrong of course, but the presence or absence of human population in the Americas has nothing to do with the point of the OP.

Comment: JDM,   Augustine (my version) :  "_Oke... assumed that there are Antipodes, BUT then it does not follow bla3x. So, because it does not follow bla3x IF there are Antipodes, then that there are Antipodes is a fable_". Augustine (your version) : _"that there are Antipodes is not a fable BUT these Antipodes are inhabited is a fable"_. The text read that Augustine said : _"But as to **the fable that there are Antipodes**_".

Comment: JDM, (your version) : _"**because** it is scientifically demonstrated that the world is of a round (hence, there are Antipodes) then there are Antipodes is not a fable. The text read that Augustine said : _"**although** it be supposed or scientifically demonstrated that the world is of a round"_

Comment: @karma, you're completely turned around and misreading, misconstruing the Augustine quote entirely.  His starting point and his whole point was that it "is on no ground credible" that "Antipodes" exist, hence he derided the idea as a "fable."  In explaining his assertion he "backs up" to the question of the earth's shape, *admitting* it to be spherical.  But he then goes on to assert that this fact by itself is not enough to conclude that the opposite side has dry land, let alone that people live on that dry land.  So again, the quote does not support the OP, in fact it contradicts it.

Comment: So, the one which a fable  in Augustine's view is (a) that there are Antipodes ? or (b) that the Antipodes are inhabited, JDM ? I'm sorry I don't quite understand your sentence. To me, it seems you say : that Antipodes exist is a fable in Augustine's pov (_his whole point was that it "is on no ground credible" that "Antipodes" exist, hence he derided the idea as a "fable."_)  - but then you say : Antipodes exist is a fact in Augustine's pov (_he then goes on to assert that **this fact** by itself is not enough to conclude that the opposite side has dry land__

Comment: @karma, OK, now I see the confusion point.  You're thinking of  "Antipodes" as a place.  But Augustine's use of the word is a reference to people, not a place.  *"But as to the fable that there are Antipodes, that is to say, men on the opposite side of the earth...."*  By Antipodes he meant men.

Answer (score -2):

I am a believer in "young-earth creation" and a flat, "domed" earth as per a as-literal-as-possible reading of the Bible (I prefer KJV for English).

From becoming a "flat-earther" in the past few years, it is definitely clear that young-earth-creationism is not always 100% linked to flat-earth belief, be it Christians or non-Christians.

For Christians as you can see in this thread, even though you have pointed out how a strongly-literal reading of the Bible indicates not only a young but flat earth, there are many Christians that may believe in the young earth but still a globe earth.

FWIW, a secular comparison can be seen in geocentric and/or "electric universe" science researchers, etc. that hold to the globe earth belief but strongly question the Copernican and/or relativistic principle(s).

To sum up, there are many parallel Christian and secular investigations of young/old earth, aliens/demons, globe/flat earth, geocentric/heliocentric and electric/gravitational "universe". Throw in the spiritual realm and/or multidimensional universe and simulation theory... Well, suffice to say that's really why we need the guidance of Jesus and the Holy Spirit, Praise God.

For further reading see Rob Skiba's site and videos: http://testingtheglobe.com/

Comment: I can't see anything about creationism on Skiba's site.

Comment: @saltysub, If the literal reading leads to a literal assertion of a flat earth, you should at least supply the relevant quotations.  As noted in my comment above to karma, the two verses quoted make no such assertion as they relate to visions, not literal seeings.

Comment: I suggest that you review the [how to answer a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) at the help center.  Supported answers get votes and stay around, unsupported answers do not.